# Java printf Flags order

Tags: java, printf, formatexception

Is there any specific order I have to follow while using flags in the printf?

```
1.System.out.printf("%+04d + %s ", 12, "a");// include sign then pad zeros      
2.System.out.printf("\n%04+d + %s ", 12, "a");// pad zeros then include sign    
3.System.out.printf("\n%+-4d + %s ", 12, "a");// include sign then left justify 
4.System.out.printf("\n%-4+d + %s ", 12, "a");// left justify then include sign 


The answer is: 

+012 + a 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '0'
+12  + a 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yea, there are lots of specific things you need to follow when using `printf`.  They are described in the javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html.  Hint: flags, then width, then conversion.   For more detail, read the javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the order matter, that's why you getting exception with some combinations:

```
% [flags][width][.precision] conversion-character (square brackets denote optional parameters)
```

Thanks